# CSS3 :Iframe not taking 100% height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have 2 bootstrap columns.

in the first column there is a fixed position div. and in the 2nd column I have an iframe div.
I have given **iframe height="100%"** but it is not taking 100% of the browser.

```css
.left_side_div{
  width:25%;
  min-height:100%;
  background : #FFFFFF;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:thin black solid;
}

.iframe_div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:thin black solid;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
  <div class="left_side_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
  <div class="iframe_div">
    <iframe src="http://google.co.in/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6zLaktx/2/)

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use % for height insted use 100vh.

Comment: if i use 100vh then i get 2 scroll bars. one of the browser and another of the iframe.  i have only 2 div in the whole page. 1st that is of left_side and on the right side , entire iframe will be there.

Comment: @Rishi Use `overflow:hidden` with `height:100vh`

Comment: just want to ask that IE10,IE11 and Safari Browsers support 100vh ??

Comment: yes, look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Answer (score 0):

use margin 0 for row

```
.row{
   margin: 0;
}
```